# Erlang source code guide

Tags: c, erlang, code-structure

I am interested in delving into Erlang's C [source code](http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_R14B.tar.gz) and try to understand  what is going on under the hood. Where can I find info on the design and structure of the code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all, you might want to have a look to [**Joe Armstrong's thesis**](http://www.sics.se/~joe/thesis/armstrong_thesis_2003.pdf), introducing Erlang at a high level. It will be useful to get an idea of what was the idea behind the language. Then, you could focus on the Erlang Run Time System (**erts**). The **erlang.erl** module could be a good start. Then, I would focus on the applications who constitutes the so-called *minimal release*, **kernel** and **stdlib**. Within the stdlib, have a look on how *behaviours* are implemented. May I suggest the **gen_server.erl** module as a start?

Comment: Orignal link it's 404, try this one: http://erlang.org/download/armstrong_thesis_2003.pdf

Answer (score 9):

**A Guide To The Erlang Source** 
http://www.trapexit.org/A_Guide_To_The_Erlang_Source

Comment: This link is dead. I looked for it but couldn't find it. Does anyone else have a link?

Comment: Try here: https://web.archive.org/web/20120324223354/http://www.trapexit.org/A_Guide_To_The_Erlang_Source

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that there is no good guide.  And the code is not very well documented.

I recommend finding someone in your neighbourhood that knows the code reasonably well, and buy them dinner in exchange for a little chat.

If you don't have the possibility to do that, then I recommend starting with the loader.

```
./erts/emulator/beam/beam_load.c
```

Some useful information can also be found by pretty printing the beam representation.  I don't know whether there is any way to do so supplied by OTP, but the HiPE project has some cheats.

```
hipe:c(MODULE, [pp_beam]).
```

Should get you started.

(And I also recommend Joe's book.)

Answer (score 3):

Pretty printer of beam can be done by 'erlc -S', which is equivalent with hipe:c(M, [pp_beam]) mentioned by Daniel.

I also use `erts_debug:df(Module).` to disassemble the loaded beam code, which are instructions actually been interpreted by the VM.

Sometimes I use a debugger. OTP delivers tools supporting gdb very well. See example usage at http://www.erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2008-September/037793.html

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party here. If you just download the source from [GitHub](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/HOWTO/INSTALL.md) the internal documentation is really good. You have to generate some of it using `make`.

Get the documentation built and most of the relevant source is under `/erts` (Erlang Run Time System)

Edit: [BEAM Wisdoms](http://beam-wisdoms.clau.se/en/latest/) is also a really good guide but it may or may not be what you're after.